# How to resolve 'Unexpected value & mapping error in YAML file (Azure DevOps)'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-web-app-service

For my ASP .Net Core project, I am trying to integrate CI/CD with Azure.

There, I tried to create an Azure pipeline with GitHub as follows:
[image]

Since I have already created `.yml` file in my GitHub Repository I decided to go with the option **Existing Azure Pipeline YAML file** option.
[image]

I have already created the following `yml` file in the Github repo in the path `.github/workflows/dotnet.yml`

Here is the dotnet.yml file:

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
#     - name: Test
#       run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
```

But I am getting the two errors as:

> /.github/workflows/dotnet.yml(Line: 3, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'on'
> /.github/workflows/dotnet.yml(Line: 10, Col: 1): A mapping was not
> expected

I do not understand why I am getting these errors. When I push to the repository the .NET builds run and it builds successfully.

Can somebody please let me know how to solve these two errors and what the fault in my YAML file is?

Comment: That's a GitHub Actions YAML definition, not an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you try to run github actions build this is why its not working have a look into [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pipeline-structure) how to structure your build

In Azure pipeline it will smth like this

```
steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '5.0.x'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
  - script: dotnet build --no-restore
    displayName: 'Build'
    workingDirectory: SET_WORK_DIR
```